# Jetpack Compose Desktop: Scrollable Column/LazyColumn

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm creating a program in Jetpack Compose Desktop version 1.0.0-beta5 and I can't figure out how to make Column/LazyColumn scrollable. At the same time, it seems to me that a lot of the classes listed in the documentation for Android are missing and can not work from their examples.

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

LazyColumn(
    state = lazyListState,
    modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    items(ArrayList<String>()){ item ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}
```

This code is currently producing an error.

To be precise, the empty list used can be seen in the example, but this is just an adjustment, in fact I draw a lot of items.

Comment: I modified this code to show the List, in fact I draw a number of classes over the List.

Comment: I removed all the modifiers and remember functions and I was left with this. `LazyColumn {
        items(ArrayList<String>()){ item ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }`. Unfortunately, scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: I scrolled through the text and nothing happened. That's why I decided to use a different mouse. It seems to work well with it, so it's probably unsupported hardware.

Comment: You can report it to [official GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb) including  your mouse model and sample project you're using.

Comment: You could try 'ScrollableTabRow' It is not a perfect solution but might work

Answer (score 2):

you can achive this like this:

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
LazyRow(
    state = scrollState,
        modifier = Modifier
        .draggable(
            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    scrollState.scrollBy(-delta)
                }    
            },
        )
) {
    items(100) {
        Text("Test Test Test Test $it")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but you can take a look at [Desktop Compoments](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Desktop_Components)

Jetpack compose is for the android framework,
Compose desktop is a flavor of Jetpack compose, it uses Skia and Swing under the hood